# How to draw bloks top to bottom in the PlantUML/Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, plantuml

I want to draw like my drawing(first photo) in the plantUML(second photo) but I can not align box top to bottom. How can I do that? My plant UML code:

```
@startuml
digraph dfd{
  node[shape=record]
  {
  scheduler[label="<f0> scheduler"];
  store1 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store2 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store3 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f0> D"];
  store4 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
  store5 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store6 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store7 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
  store8 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
  store9 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store10 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
  store11 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
  store12 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
  proc1 [label="{<f0> 1|<f1> totalTimeRead\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];
  }  
subgraph cluster_0 {
    rank=same;
    store1 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
        store2 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
        store3 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
        store4 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];

        label = "process #1";
}

  store1:f1 -> proc1:f0;
  store2:f1 -> proc1:f0;
  store3:f1 -> proc1:f0;
  store4:f1 -> proc1:f0;
  proc1:f1 -> store5:f0;  
  proc1:f1 -> store6:f0;  
  proc1:f1 -> store7:f0;  
  proc1:f1 -> store8:f0;  

  proc2 [label="{<f0> 2|<f1> updateTotalTime\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];

  store5:f1 -> proc2:f0;
  store6:f1 -> proc2:f0;
  store7:f1 -> proc2:f0;
  store8:f1 -> proc2:f0;

  proc2:f1 -> store9:f0;  
  proc2:f1 -> store10:f0;
  proc2:f1 -> store11:f0;  
  proc2:f1 -> store12:f0;
  
}
@enduml
```

https://ibb.co/b7Kqb0W   (my drawing)

https://ibb.co/4dDW9Nq   (plantUML photo)

I tried rankdir prompt for top to bottom align but I see this prompt change whole file. And I do not want to this.

Comment: The content (not just layout) of your plantURL graph is different form the draw.io graph.  Please provide a (hand-drawn) sketch of your desired graph

Comment: I drew the graphic I wanted, see the first photo please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A re-worked version of your input.
It could also have been done by replacing each cluster and contents with a single html-like node (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

```
digraph dfd{
  compound=true  // allow edges to terminate at cluster
  ranksep=.2     // bring nodes within clusters closer together
  node[shape=record]
  edge[style=invis]  // invisible edges within clusters to determine ranking (rows)

subgraph cluster_0 {
    //rank=same;
    store1 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store2 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store3 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store4 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store1->store2->store3->store4  // establish ranking
    label = "process #1";
}

subgraph cluster_1 {
    //rank=same;
    store5 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store6 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store7 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store8 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store5->store6->store7->store8
    label = "process #2";
}

subgraph cluster_2 {
    //rank=same;
    store9 [label="<f0> firstTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store10 [label="<f0> secondTotalTimeBlockAddress|<f1> D"];
    store11 [label="<f0> firstTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store12 [label="<f0> secondTotalTime|<f1> D"];
    store9->store10->store11->store12
    label = "process #3";
}

  scheduler[label="<f0> scheduler"];
  proc1 [label="{<f0> 1|<f1> totalTimeRead\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];
  proc2 [label="{<f0> 2|<f1> updateTotalTime\n\n\n}" shape=Mrecord];

  // make edges visible & increase node-to-node spacing
  edge[style=solid  minlen=2]
  scheduler->store1 [lhead=cluster_0]
  store4->proc1     [ltail=cluster_0]
  proc1->store5     [lhead=cluster_1]
  store8->proc2     [ltail=cluster_1]
  proc2->store9     [lhead=cluster_2]
}
```

Giving:
[image]